# How to fade in changes to elements in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I am trying to fade in edits to elements in CSS when an element is hovered over. Specifically changing a `border` from `solid` to `dotted`, by fading in the change, how do I do that?

EDIT:

Perhaps I need to be more specific about context here is my current code:

```
li {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

li:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: Generally, with `transition`. But you can't `transition` the `border-style` property, sorry. You'll need a second element that you can cross-fade over it...

Comment: Some properties cannot be faded but generally you can use `transition: all ease 1s` where `1s` represent the duration over which the fading occurs in seconds. I would use a `pseudo-element` and transition its `opacity` on `:hover` instead

Comment: [Here's a cross-fade example](https://jsfiddle.net/23r0psjc/) using pseudo-elements.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/b2ev3g5L/) is some CSS trickery that gives that effect. The downside being the inside cannot be transparent.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  border: 3px dotted red;
  background: red;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out all;
}

div:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: ' ';
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: white;
}

div:hover {
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Nice—using `after` makes this a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

You could place 2 divs on top of each other with different stroke types then transition them out.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  display: flex;
}
div {
  width: 11rem;
  height: 11rem;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border: 5px #bbb solid;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.dotted {
  border: 5px #bbb dotted;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate( -50%, -50% );
  z-index: 0;
}
.solid {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}
.solid:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="solid"></div>
<div class="dotted"></div>
```

Comment: Better done with pseudo elements instead of extra markup, but still a good method.

Comment: True. Pseudo would be one line less of HTML and maybe a bit more elegant CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using pseudoelements. This version works even with transparent background. Added gradient to body to show this.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  
  /* just styles for demo */
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out all;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

div:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: ' ';
  top: -5px;
  bottom: -5px;
  left: -5px;
  right: -5px;
  border-width: inherit;
  border-style: dotted;
  border-radius: inherit;
}

div, div:after {
  border-color: tomato;
}

div:hover {
  border-color: transparent;
}

/* just styles for demo showing that this will work even for transparent background */
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, #ddd);
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a soo elegant solution but it goes off of 'Niet the Dark Absol's' comment on my original question. Here is the code:

```
li {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent; /* invisible border */
}

li:before, li:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; right: 0;
  top: 0; bottom: 0;
  margin: -1px; /* same as border width */
  transition: opacity 1s linear;
}

li:before {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

li:after {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #000;
  opacity: 0;
}

li:hover:before {
  opacity: 0;
}

li:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```